# Hexagonal tiling of the plane: looking for the expression of a translation vector

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I am coding a board game called "HEX" and the board is a parallelogram. My problem is that I don't know how to express the distance between a hexagon (0;0) and another hexagon (0;1). I guess we have to use trigonometry but being not very good in math I don't know how to do it. Hopefully someone can help me! Thanks !

you will more understand with the image :
[image: picture]

Comment: 1) Is your orange line meaning that you join the center of the first hexagon $C_1(0,0)$ with the second center $C_2(x,y)$ ? 2) What is exactly your question ? Expressing coordinates $(x,y)$ as functions of the sidelength $s$ of the hexagons ?

Comment: In fact I would like to know what I have to add in the x and y coordinates of the hexagon A1 to go to the hexagon A2

Comment: Let $s$ be the sidelength of the hexagons (which is also the radius of the circumscribed circles). Then you have to add $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}s$ for the abscissa, and subtract $\frac{3}{2}s$ for the ordinate.

Comment: For an horizontal translation, just add abscissa $\sqrt{3}s $ to the abscissa.